# How to get keys length found in Ionic2 Storage (IndexedDB)

Tags: ionic2, ionic-native

I am trying to use Ionic2 Storage , which use Indexed DB on browser. How can I get total number of keys in storedin DB.

**this._storage.length() gives me t {__zone_symbol__state: null, __zone_symbol__value: Array[0]}**

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer, this._storage.length() returns promise

```
  this._storage.length().then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
  })
```